# Making a breadcrumb out of a link, tips?

Tags: jquery, html, css, portfolio

I've got a little question. I am busy to make my own website:

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Now there is one thing where I find some problems;
I want to let my visitor know which part of the site he is looking at.

For example;

If you hover across the links now, you'll get a black background. But i want that background to stay as long you are on that specific page.

So if you click on 'contact' the black background will be visible at that link as long you stay on that page.

Comment: I can see you utilize the hashtag for routing, so why not use that as well for setting your menu background.

Comment: what about adding a class with javascript?

Comment: Please post your relevant code (to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) in your question; don't just link to your site (because once your problem is solved the question becomes meaningless to everyone else in the future).

Answer (score 2):

Create a class active with the same hover style and add it to link on click and change it on scroll or when you click the other link as follows

Add this to your CSS

```
.menu a.active {
color: #fff;
background-color: black;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Add this to your JS

```
$(function(){
//onclick
$('.menu a').click(function(){
$('.menu a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
//onscroll
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook up to the `scroll` event of the document. Here's a fiddle I found: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/ .

During scrolling, the `onScroll` callback checks which `div` is currently visible. It does that by comparing the current position of the scrollbar (more or less - `scrollPos`) with positions and heights of all the `div` containers. If it finds a match, it adds a certain class `active` to the link in the menu. For all other `div`s, `active` class is removed.

The JavaScript code also contains smooth scrolling, but you have it already implemented so you can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple method would be:

Define a style for an `.active` class in your CSS like this:

```
.menu a:hover,
.menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And add some javascript that toggles the class on the clicked element:

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtbmvt5n/) for a quick working example.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the code in your page. I would suggest you to do two minor changes.

Edit css.css on line 77 and add an additional selector to that css definition for the links that has the "active":

```
.menu a:visited, 
.menu a.active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
}
```

You will also have to modify the script.js to toggle the "active" class on the links when the user clicks on them, I've added them with comments see:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-typer-targets]').typer();
});

$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

      // removes the active class from all the link in the menu
      $('a', $(this).parent().parent()).toggleClass('active', false); 
      // adds the active class to the link that was clicked
      $(this).toggleClass('active', true); 

      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I hoe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have made something similar using Waypoint http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/ for the scroll function

```
// On Scroll Change Nav
    jQuery('.bullseye').waypoint(function(direction) {
        var idThis = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        if(direction === 'down'){
            jQuery('a.scroll').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('a[href="#'+idThis+'"]').addClass('active');
            //console.log(idThis);
        }         
    }, { offset: 75 });

    jQuery('.bullseye').waypoint(function(direction) {
        var idThis = jQuery(this).attr('id');

        if(direction === 'up'){
            jQuery('a.scroll').removeClass('active');
            jQuery('a[href="#'+idThis+'"]').addClass('active');
            //console.log(idThis);
        }         
    }, { offset: 'bottom-in-view' });
```

Where .bullseye is the class you need to add to the sections (#home, #about, #portfolio, #contact).

And then a script for the click event on the menu(you need to add a .scroll class to the menu links or just remodel the script)

```
// Smooth Scroll
    jQuery('a.scroll[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        jQuery('a.scroll').removeClass('active');           
        var hrefMatch = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        jQuery('a[href="'+hrefMatch+'"]').addClass('active');

    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = jQuery(this.hash);       
      target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 75
        }, 1000);

        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

And last but not the least, for the active class to work

```
.menu a.active{
color: #fff;
background-color: black;
padding: 5px;
}
```

And that's it basically :) 
Vote me up if you make it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('ul.menu a').each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('activePage', this.getAttribute('href') === window.location.hash);
});
```

Or simply:

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').addClass('activePage');
```